# Reset ID column of database records

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a problem which can not solve by myself. My customer request reset button which provide delete all records and reset ID.

There is not problem for delete records but i can not reach reset id.

```
private void SettingsDLT_delete_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainWeight main = new MainWeight();
    main.RemoveAllWeight();
}
```

And controller:

```
public void RemoveAllWeight()
{
    try
    {
        using (DaghanKantarEntities context = new DaghanKantarEntities())
        {
            context.tbl_MainWeight.RemoveRange(
                context.tbl_MainWeight.Where(c => c.fldId != null));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        throw new Exception("Hata: Kayıt Silinemedi - " + exp.Message.ToString(), exp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to reset Ids? They are typically considered internal to system and you would want to maintain the references it might have had with other tables. There lot of information missing in your question which would make it difficult to answer your question. For instance, how is the ID column configured in your DB?

Comment: If you delete the records aren't the Ids automatically deleted?  They may be another table in the database that contains the last used Id number.  Usually adding Ids to a database is done inside a stored procedure in the database.   You will have to open SQL Server Management Studio and check if there are any stored procedure that is crating the Ids and find the table with the Last assigned Id.

Comment: you should clarify in your question,  what database softwareyou are using, what your ID field is in your database, people are assuming it is an autoincrementing field in SQL server, but you should explicitly state it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with SQL Server Management Studio you can reseed the primary key. You could run the following as a raw query rather than through entity:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, 1)
```

You could also TRUNCATE table_name instead of deleting all records.

Comment: Thanks for your help but . I am using Entity Model so, ı do not know where should this code write ?

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx @SemihCanBilgen

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, don't do like me, double check that the account have DBO authorization in order to execute that kind of code

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helps. I have solved my problem and will share codes for example. Regards.

```
private void SettingsDLT_delete_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainWeight main = new MainWeight();
        main.ResetId();

    }
```

And Controller side

```
        public void ResetId()
    {
         try
        {
            using (DaghanKantarEntities context = new DaghanKantarEntities())
            {
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.tbl_MainWeight");
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('tbl_MainWeight', RESEED, 0)");
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Hata: Kayıt Resetlenemedi - " + exp.Message.ToString(), exp);
        }

    }
```